# How to clone and rename a project in Visual Studio 2017?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2017

I have a Project & Solution **.sln** in Visual Studio 2017. How to **rename** it in **Visual Studio 2017**?

It is written in C#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally managed to figured it out as below;

1. Rename the project : 
   [**WindowsFormsApplication2** to **NewName**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y9bWc.png)
2. Rename the output folder to NewName :
   [**WindowsFormsApplication2** to **NewName**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ViFiS.png)
3. Open the Solution (WindowsFormsApplication2.sln) with VisualStudio 2017 and 
   [**Right click** to rename WindowsFormsApplication2 to NewName](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SfZ2A.png)
   Make sure to **rename both** Project name and Solution name
4. Open Solution's properties from Project-> NewName properties Tool Menu and 
   [Rename **Assembly Name**, ** Default Namespace** also **Assembly info** with **NewName**](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wuNS5.png)
5. Open one of the ***.cs** file and rename the namespace from:
   **namespace WindowsFormsApplication2** to **namespace NewName** using **right click** on WindowsFormsApplication2

Now both the Project and Solution should be fully renamed and able to build/rebuild.

Comment: Isn't there some project GUID you have to update?